# How to implement single logger in python for two scripts one defining the workflow and one containing all functions?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have two python scripts one as workflow.py and other is task.py. The workflow.py defines the workflow of the task.py and thus it has only main inside it in which it instantiate the constructor of task.py. The structure of worflow.py is as follows:

```
workflow.py
from optparse import OptionParser
from optparse import OptionGroup
from task import *
def main():
        dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))

    try:
        parser = parse_options(parser, dir)
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
        print ("everything working fine in workflow")
    except SystemExit:
        return 0
    task_object = task_C(options.source_dir, options.target, options.build_dir)
    print ("workflow is reached")
    task_object.another_funct()
    ##following 3 lines is when set_logger is defined
    log = task_object .set_logger()
    log.info(""workflow is reached"")
    log.info("more info if required")


def parser(parser, dir):
        group = OptionGroup(parser, "Prepare")
        group.add_option("-t", "--target",action="store", dest="target",
                      help="Specifies the target.")
        group.add_option("-s", "--Source",action="store", dest="source_dir",
                      help="Specifies the source dir.")
        group.add_option("-b", "--build",action="store", dest="build_dir",
                      help="Specifies the build dir.")
        parser.add_option_group(group)


task.py
class task_C():
   def __init__(self, source_dir, target, build_dir):
     self.target = self.settargetplatform(target)
     self.source_dir = self.setsourcedir(source_dir)
     self.build_dir = self.setbuilddir(build_dir)

   def settargetplatform( target):
    ...sets target dir
   def setsourcedir(source_dir ):
    ...sets source_dir
   def setbuilddir(build_dir):
    ..sets build_dir
   def another_funct( ):
    print ("inside the another funct")
    print ("some usefull info")
    print ("...")
   ##following part after adding set_logger then using logger
    log = self.set_logger()
    log.info( "inside the another funct")
    log.info( " some usefull info")
    log.info ("...")
    .
  def set_logger(self):
        logging.basicConfig()
        l = logging.getLogger('root')
        l.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter(' %(levelname)s : %(message)s')
        fileHandler = logging.FileHandler(self.build_dir+"/root.log", mode='w')
        fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter)    
        l.addHandler(fileHandler)
```

Now, as in the above script it is shown that the task.py constructor is invoked inside the workflow and there are various print statements in both script, i would like to have a logger instead of the print statements and for that purpose i want to place the log inside the location "build_dir" but that location is set inside the task.py and i don't want to add another function inside workflow.py which retrieve back the 'build_dir'. I added set_logger() function inside task.py  as you can see in the task.py which could serve my purpose but the log i am getting contains all NULL NULL NULL...so on. So, suggest me how can i have one log containing all print statements in these two script and what improvements do i need to make?

Answer (score 1):

> actually that can be done but the point is in that case log location
>   has to be defined in workflow.py and i don't want to define location
>   there as it is already defined in task.py. In workflow i don't want to
>   define the same location for logger which is already set in task.py

As per your above comment - 
Then you can call your `set_logger()` in `worker.py` and pass it to `task.py` i.e. have the following lines in `worker.py`:

```
task_object = task_C(options.source_dir, options.target, options.build_dir)
log = task_object .set_logger()
```

For any call to task methods, pass the logger (methods must accept it as param) - for example:

```
task_object.another_funct(log=log)
```

---

For logging not working properly - add `return l` at the end of `set_logger()` in `task.py`

Answer (score -1):

I think I would define logger inside `workflow.py` and pass it as a parameter into the constructor of `task_C`. That would seem to be the easiest solution.

Comment: actually that can be done but the point is in that case log location has to be defined in workflow.py and i don't want to define location there as it is already defined in task.py. In workflow i don't want to define the same location for logger which is already set in task.py.